# How can I disconnect GA360 from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, google-analytics

I would like to disconnect my Google Analytics account from Marketing Cloud, but I can't see any option or button to do this within setup.

How can I do this? Do I need to open a ticket with support?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Parent/Enterprise level, go to Setup > Apps > Google Analytics Integration. There is an Unlink Button